# UserDefaults is confusing the data

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, nsuserdefaults

in my code when the user enters to the app I give him/her a token and I save it with UserDefaults, and later somewhere else in the app user can set the address as the main address and I save it by UserDefaults.
when I do that first, it deletes the token that I saved with user default in constantKey.token and then it puts "65" in the address constant.address! although the address is not "65"

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(self.Main[indexPath.row].AddressLine, forKey: constantAddress.addressLine)
```

////

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(self.Main[indexPath.row].ProvinceName, forKey: ConstantsKey.stateName)
UserDefaults.standard.set(self.Main[indexPath.row].ProvinceId, forKey: constantAddress.stateId)
UserDefaults.standard.set(self.Main[indexPath.row].CityName, forKey: constantAddress.cityName)
UserDefaults.standard.set(self.Main[indexPath.row].CityId, forKey: constantAddress.cityId)
UserDefaults.standard.set(self.Main[indexPath.row].AddressLine, forKey: constantAddress.addressLine)
UserDefaults.standard.set(self.Main[indexPath.row].PostalCode, forKey: constantAddress.postalCode)
UserDefaults.standard.set(self.Main[indexPath.row].Tel, forKey: constantAddress.telephone)
UserDefaults.standard.set(self.Main[indexPath.row].Mobile, forKey: constantAddress.mobile)
UserDefaults.standard.set(self.Main[indexPath.row].Id, forKey: constantAddress.Id)



class constantAddress {
    static var Id = ""
    static var stateName = ""
    static var stateId = "0"
    static var cityName = ""
    static var cityId = "0"
    static var addressLine = ""
    static var postalCode = ""
    static var telephone = ""
    static var mobile = ""
}
```

It doesn't save the the item's value in to constantAddress

getting data from userdefualts:

```
StateLbl.text = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: constantAddress.stateName)
CityLbl.text = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: constantAddress.cityName)
AddressLbl.text = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: constantAddress.addressLine)
PostalCodeLbl.text = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: constantAddress.postalCode)
TelLbl.text = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: constantAddress.telephone)
MobileLbl.text = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: constantAddress.mobile)
```

Comment: You should [edit] your question to include the actual code causing the problem in the form of a [mcve].

Comment: Is `constantAddress.addressLine` == `ConstantsKey.token`? Also could you give some of the keys/values you are using, and where you see it's wrong?

Comment: **Certainly** `UserDefaults` works correctly, you have a bug in ***your*** code.

Comment: _Swift Tip:_ always use `lowerCamelCase` for Swift variables / func names e.g. `addressLine` not `AddressLine`, `main` not `Main`

Comment: @luk2302 as you can see I'm passing different things to userdefualts and when I try to get the data from userdefalts , all of them show "65"

Comment: Where's the code to _get_ a value from `UserDefaults`?

Comment: as I can see all `ConstantsKey.*` can still be the same thing, like `""`.

Comment: @luk2302 why ? :|

Comment: @AshleyMills updated

Comment: `static var mobile = ""` and `static var telephone = ""` => SAME KEY.

Comment: @luk2302 I defined with "" , but Even I'm not getting "", I'm getting "65"

Comment: You still don't understand how a key-value map works, `""` is the KEY, if you have two constants which represent `""` they will access the same object in the map.

Answer (score 0):

You're using different keys to set and get from `UserDefaults`

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(self.Main[indexPath.row].ProvinceName, forKey: ConstantsKey.stateName)
```

uses `ConstantsKey.stateName`

```
StateLbl.text = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: constantAddress.stateName)
```

uses `constantAddress.stateName`

Assuming that `ConstantsKey.stateName` has a String value, what you need to say is…

```
StateLbl.text = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: ConstantsKey.stateName)
```

*Please* read the documentation for `UserDefaults` thoroughly… https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults

Comment: And almost all `constantAddress.*` have the same value and therefore cannot be used as proper keys.

Comment: i've trying something , that is the reason they were not matched  , I fixed it , check it pls

Comment: This is worse. You're _still_ using the **empty string** for every key, and now you're using it to _set_ values as well  - **this will not work**. Use `ConstantsKey.` not `constantAddress.`  for your keys